# Question About Datagridview Format Styling

Tags: vb.net

i want to Show Thousand Separator in Datagridview Column
So i added One Column in datagridview so i Run this code But It's not working with me
[image]

[image]

Comment: This site prefers code as text, not images.

Comment: Is the data actually numeric or is it text that looks like numbers? I'm guessing the latter. You can only format numbers using numeric format specifiers.

Comment: By the way, why use `With DataGridView2` and then repeat `.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle` within the block? Why would you not use `With DataGridView2.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle`?

Comment: This is Not Date .. this is Debt Column ..   and thanks for you respond :)

Comment: Who said anything about dates? I asked if the data was numbers or text? A `string` containing numeric characters is still a `string` and you can't format a `string`. If you expect to format a number, you need to actually have a number to format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the column's [`ValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) if you don't have a  DataSource to bind (ex. `DataTable`) which is the source of the data types as well. Here, you need a column of a numeric type such as `Decimal`.

So, **before** you populate the grid or add new rows, do:

```vb
With DataGridView2.Columns(0)
    .ValueType = GetType(Decimal)
    .DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,#.##"
End With
```

In case the control is bound to DataSource, make sure that the type of the data field/property in question is numeric.

Comment: Bro thank you very Much it's solved Buy i made Format="N2"  is ther any problem or diffrent between this format and yours "#,#.##" ?

Comment: @AhmedSaif Sure, you are welcome. No problem, use any one.